# How to remove all lines in a file containing a variable, only when located on a line somewhere between braces in BASH?

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to remove all of the matches of `$word` from a file, but only on lines where `$word` is placed somewhere within `{` and `}` which also appear on the same line, e.g.:

```
{The cat liked} the fish.
The mouse {did not like} the cat.
The {cat did not} like the spider.
```

If `$word` is set to "cat", then lines 1 and 3 are deleted, because "cat" appears between the `{` and `}`. If `$word` is set to "like", then lines 1 and 2 are deleted, because this search term appears on those lines between the `{` and `}`. Line 3 is not deleted, because `like` appears outside of the braces.

- The braces are never nested.
- The braces never appear split across lines.

I have tried various things, but these all returned errors:

```
sed -i "/\{*$word*\}/d" ./file.txt

sed -i "/\{.*$word.*\}/d" ./file.txt

sed -i "/\{(.*)$word(.*)\}/d" ./file.txt
```

How can I remove all of the lines in a file containing a variable, but only when the found variable was on a line and found between two braces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -i "/{.*$word.*}/d" ./file.txt
```

`\{` in sed actually have a special meaning, not the literal `{`, you should just write a `{` to represent the literal character. (which would be confusing if you are well familiar with perl regex ...)

**Edit:**

Be careful with `-i`, if this is in a script, and accidently `$word` is not defined or set to empty string, this command will delete **all** lines containing `{ no matter what between }`.

Answer (score 3):

I would take the answer that @cybeliak gave a little further. If you really want to match `cat` and not, say `scat`, then you need to delimit your expression with word boundaries:

```
sed '/{.*[[:<:]]'$word'[[:>:]].*}/d'
```

Note - I prefer to use `' '` style quotes to prevent any unintended side-effects...

As an aside, I am a big fan of *not* using the `-i` flag. Pipe the result into a different file and confirm for yourself that it's good, before deleting the original.

Comment: @jaypal - I think they look like emoticons. Certainly give a new meaning to "expression". :-) (or should I say `[:>` ? )

Comment: As long as they are happy! `;)`!!

Comment: Looking at the examples OP gave (like vs liked), I somehow don't think word boundaries are applicable here.

Comment: @abhishekBansal fair point - I was misled by the use of `$word` as a variable name...

Answer (score 2):

Much easier to do with awk:

```
awk -v s="cat" -F '[{}]' '!($2 ~ s)' file
The mouse {did not like} the cat.

awk -v s="like" -F '[{}]' '!($2 ~ s)' file
The {cat did not} like the spider.
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/{[^}]*'"$word"'[^}]*}/d' file
```

N.B. `$word`should not contain `}` or `/`.